# Looking for replacement of these Magic Variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, multiple-inheritance

I designed this OOPs code with magic variable actually it feel little complicated so I want to rectify this code to simplest one without using Magic variable.Below code is Inheritance in Python.

And I'm in learning phase of OOPs concepts please suggest me best OOPs practice and which concepts are important in OOPs on perspective of programmer job.

```
 class Bike():
    bmodel = ''
    def __init__(self,**model):
        self.bmodel = model.get('bmodel')
        super(Bike,self).__init__(**model)

    def setmodelb(self,bmodel):
        self.bmodel = bmodel

    def getmodel(self):
        return self.bmodel

    def tostringb(self):
        print("Licence",self.lno,"is Bike and Model is",self.bmodel)

class Car():
    cmodel = ''
    def __init__(self,**model):
        self.cmodel = model.get('cmodel')
        super(Car,self).__init__()

    def setmodelc(self,cmodel):
        self.cmodel = cmodel

    def getmodel(self):
        return self.cmodel

    def tostringc(self):
        print("Licence",self.lno,"is Car and Model is",self.cmodel)

class Vehicle(Bike,Car):
    lno = ''
    def __init__(self,**model):
        self.lno = model.get('lno')
        super(Vehicle,self).__init__(**model)

    def setlno(self,lno):
        self.lno = lno

    def getlno(self):
        return self.lno

    def tostringv(self):
        print("Vehicle Licence is",self.lno)



 v = Vehicle()
    v.setlno("CALIFORNIA99")
    v.setmodelc("HONDA CITY")
    v.tostringc()
    v.tostringv()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Licence CALIFORNIA99 is Car and Model is HONDA CITY
Vehicle Licence is CALIFORNIA99
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: Your inheritance is completely upside down - a Car is a Vehicle, and a Bike is a Vehicle, but a Vehicle isn't a Car-and-Bike. Also it's not clear what you're asking for. [codereview.se], maybe (note only for **working code**)?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. I'm sure if you search at the web you'll find a plenty of resources explaining OOP.

Comment: actually condition is to don't use Magic variables thats it.

Comment: And what does *"magic variables"* mean? Which things in there do you think should be removed? If anything, you don't have *enough* Python "magic"; setters and getters should be replaced with properties, if they're even needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to OOP. Your code seems complicated also because you are not following python conventions. Here are some essential reading:

- For text: [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- For documentation: [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257)
- Use reStructuredText formatting: [PEP 287](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287)

And for a more Pythonic code: [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020).
Last but not least, avoid common pitfalls: [Anti-patterns](http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-code-patterns)

In your code, you can replace `tostring` by `__repr__` method. This allows to do `print(Car())`. Also in python you do not need getter and setter as there are no public or private variables. So only define inside your `__init__`: `self.model`. You will be able to do:

```
car = Car()
car.model = ...
```

Comment: So what are Magic Variable and how does this answer replace them?

Comment: @jonrsharpe To be honest I do not now what the OP is referring to!

Comment: Then **don't answer**, ask for clarification. If none is forthcoming, that's the OP's problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You already asked for clarification. But the other point was some advices on how to improve and better factor the code. I do not need to know what magic is here to see that this is not pythonic and can be improved ;)